# fsck error after converting Debian 8 root to LVM

Tags: debian, boot, lvm, initramfs, fsck

I've (mostly) successfully split my Debian 8 root filesystem into a `/boot` partition (still on my original disk) and a `/` partition (using LVM on a second disk).

The system boots fine, but the initramfs (at least I assume it is that) is complaining that it can't check the root filesystem:

```
fsck error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext3 for /dev/mapper/SSDVG-RootVol
fsck exited with status code 8
```

There is then a successful `fsck` of the same filesystem from (I think) systemd.

As far as I can tell, all files in `/etc/initramfs-tools` and `/usr/share/initramfs-tools` are identical to a system originally built as LVM, which does not have this issue.

Is the problem that my initramfs is not loading the LVM support early enough, or that my new root filesystem is somehow not being identified correctly? (I see it is looking for `fsck.ext3`, where other logs I've seen online suggest it may usually use `fsck.ext4`.

Any advice on where to look to diagnose what is going on appreciated - the Debian grub2 / initramfs behaviour with LVM appears to be rather lightly documented!

Comment: Have you regenerated your initramfs image after the split? Try booting with `break` (see `man initramfs-tools`) and troubleshoot the problem at the `(initramfs)` shell prompt.

Comment: The problem did indeed turn out to be that the new root filesystem did not have enough `ext4` features, so it was trying to check it as `ext3` and failing. Booting back into a live distribution and following a guide to convert the filesystem to `ext4` has solved that problem (and probably improved performance too)

Answer (score 0):

The problem did indeed turn out to be that the new root filesystem did not have enough ext4 features, so it was trying to check it as ext3 and failing.

Booting back into a live distribution and following a guide to convert the filesystem to ext4 has solved that problem (and probably improved performance too.

The guide I used was:

https://debian-administration.org/article/643/Migrating_a_live_system_from_ext3_to_ext4_filesystem